# what is the Dimension of the given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

If  $I≠T∈M_4(C)$ has  $(x-1)^4 $ as it characteristics polynomial then what is the largest Dimension of the centralizer of T in$ M_4(C)$(= the subspace of all matrices that commute with T) ?

my answer :First i take T=$\left(\begin{matrix} 
  1 &  0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0& 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{matrix}\right)as   $$T≠I$

I think largest dimension will be 4 that  is  Identity matrix of 4×4 matrices

Is its correct or incorrect?  Pliz tell me,,any hints will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the dimension of the centralizer of 
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1}
$$
is $6$.  In particular, it will consist of all matrices of the form
$$
\pmatrix{a_1&a_2\\&a_1\\&&b_{11}&b_{12}\\&&b_{21} & b_{22}}
$$
where the unwritten entries are $0$s.

Comment: ,@ Omnomnomnom,,it is 6 or 7  ,,im not getting

Comment: @lomberlego 6: note that the first two diagonal entries need to be the same

Comment: @Omnomnomnom..is there any particular  formula  to  find the  largest dimension of centralizer ?? i mean  in$ n\times n $matrix

Comment: Yes. All you have to do is look at the Jordan form, and do what I did here